# ”Five is less / fewer than seven”: which one is correct?

Tags: determiners

1. Five is less than seven.
2. Five is fewer than seven.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: I'd say: Five is *smaller* than seven (it is **a** smaller **number** than...). In any case use "less", it is overtaking "few/er" and many native speakers aren't even aware of the difference.

Comment: Five tons of coal is/are less than eight; five apples are fewer than seven; Five is smaller than nine.

Comment: With a little bit of added research this could have been a good/interesting question, the answer, after a first glance, is not that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> 5 is *smaller* than 7

because 5 is **a** smaller **number** than 7.

In anycase use "less", **5 is less than 7** because the determiner *less* is overtaking *few/er* and many native speakers aren't even aware of the difference.

- There is less cookies for me.
- Five cookies are less than seven.

Both forms are considered nonstandard English but native speakers *do* use “less” that way.

But if a learner has to pass an English test then the "correct" answer, the one the examiner wants is **few + countable noun** and **little + uncountable noun**

- There are few cookies today.
- Five cookies are fewer than seven.
- There is little milk in the fridge.
- Today I have less milk (than yesterday)

> ### less
>
> DETERMINER
> A smaller amount of; not as much.
>
> - ‘You are entitled to the full amount if your annual **income** is **less than** £18,900.’
> - ‘Never had he accepted anything **less than** what he wanted, not even then.’

Here's a note on its usage [emphasis in bold mine].

> **Usage**
> Fewer versus less: strictly speaking, the rule is that fewer, the comparative form of few, is used with words denoting people
> or countable things (fewer members; fewer books). Less, on the other
> hand, is used with mass nouns, denoting things which cannot be counted
> (less money; less bother). **It is regarded as incorrect in standard
> English to use less with count nouns**, as in less people or less
> words, although this is one of the most widespread errors made by
> native speakers. It is not so obvious which word should be used with
> than. **Less is normally used with numerals** (a score of less than 100)
> and with expressions of measurement or time (less than two weeks; less
> than four miles away), but fewer is used if the things denoted by the
> number are seen as individual items or units (there were fewer than
> ten contestants)
>
> Source: *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/few)*

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical use, the prefered term is "less than", or optionally "smaller than"

5 < 7 can be read as "five is [less than](https://unicode-table.com/en/003C/) seven".

This is because the numbers here are abstract.  If you actually apply these to objects and count them or measure them then the choice of word depends on  the type of stuff that you are counting/measuring:

> Five tons of coal is/are less than seven; five apples are fewer than seven  (From comment)